# How to show your app again after a call started from your app finishes?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I have an app where you can call some phone numbers from it. I successfully detected when a call starts and finishes with broadcast receiver.
 When the call finishes, a dialer app is shown. 
I want my app to show after a call (not the dialer app) to display some alerts, toasts, ...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the call ended broacast intent then when your application knows it started the call start your Activity with an Intent using the given Context.

Comment: But my activity was running just before the call. If i press back button after a call, the activity that i want is shown, so i guess i dont have to start it again?

Comment: You can adjust the flags of the intent and activity so it restores the instance already in memory or you can update your program's state so that the new instance will reflect the updated state.

Comment: You probably mean flag "singleTop"?